Why did the Men of Judah Anoint David? (2 Sam 2)
As most Bible readers know, David was anointed by Samuel to be king of all Israel. Yet, after Saul's death:

David inquired of the Lord, “Shall I go up into one of the cities of
Judah?” The Lord replied to him: Go up. Then David asked, “Where shall
I go?” He replied: To Hebron. 2 So David went up there, with his two
wives, Ahinoam of Jezreel and Abigail, the wife of Nabal of Carmel. 3
David also brought up his men with their families, and they dwelt in
the towns of Hebron. 4 Then the men of Judah came there and anointed
David king over the house of Judah.

Why did the men of Judah feel that they needed to anoint David as their king? Was his anointing by Samuel kept secret before this time?

thank you, I corrected it.

You are right. In the earlier story of David's anointing by Samuel, 1 Samuel ch16, we are told that Samuel kept the act as secret as he could; "If Saul hears it, he will kill me." (v2). So he carefully disguised the purpose of his visit to Bethlehem (v5). David was anointed "in the midst of his brothers" (v13), but we are not told that the action was explained, and it would be consistent with his previous secrecy if Samuel told the family to keep quiet.
And after David fled from Saul's court, public opinion in the land seems to have regarded him as a rebel rather than as chosen successor; "Who is the son of Jesse? There are many servants nowadays who are breaking away from their masters" (1 Samuel ch25 v10).
In any case, the men of the tribe of Judah were not anointing David as king "over all Israel" like Saul, but only over themselves.
I take it that "they anointed him" means that they arranged for it to be done in their presence. The most likely agent in the act of anointing must be his friend "Abiathar the priest, son of Abimelech" (1 Samuel ch30 v7), who kept David's favour until he chose the wrong side in the succession crisis of 1 Kings ch1.

+1 ... Thanks for mentioning vs 2 ... I had forgotten this part.

+1. Good answer.
